Kubuntu Dicover "Update All" does not update all
This is another very minor annoyance that I'd like to resolve if possible.  I believe this has only been happening since upgrading to Kubuntu 24.10.
In Discover, when there are updates available, they tend to be grouped in separate sections - Application updates and System updates.  If all updates in both sections are ticked (default) and I click the "Update all" button, only the application updates get installed.  I then have to hit update all again to install the system updates.
By way of an example, I had about half a dozen updates to install today.  One of them was the Spotify snap, listed under Applications, and the rest were system updates.  As it happens, the Spotify update failed and I had to reinstall, but Discover made no attempt to download the system updates, and this is the behaviour I've seen before.  It will download and then install the application updates, but ignore the system updates.
Any thoughts/ideas for where I could start to look at this?

Installing system updates does not require intervention by the user. System updates are often installed automatically in the background by the system instead of being installed manually in the GUI by the user. Apparently this happens regardless of what options you checked in Discover in Kubuntu 24.10.

You could remove Spotify from Snap, and re-installing it as a .deb file abd see if that makes a difference in updating.. I try to avoid installing from Discover and Snap packages as much as possible.

So, are we saying this is a feature rather than a bug?  The Spotify snap is just an example, it happens with all updates where there are updates available in both sections - it will only apply the application updates on the first pass.  The second "update all" will install the system updates.
